# my sql query is not working according

Tags: sql

[sql structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjOWC.png)

```
SELECT 
  opreator.o_name,
  city.c_name as dept,
  city.c_name as  destination,route.fare    
FROM opreator 
INNER JOIN route ON opreator.id=route.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN city ON city.id=route.dep
```

i want to print data as

```
 o_name| dep| dest|fare
```

Comment: What is the current output and why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: the current output is  o_name| dep| dep| fare

Comment: You have twice `city.c_name as ` which gives the same result naturally.

Comment: yes but my both dest and dep city came from onle coloum c_name so how can i fix it?

Comment: you can also see sql structure on aboue link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use two join on city using table alias

```
  SELECT 
    opreator.o_name,
    c1.c_name as dep,
    c2.c_name as  destination,
    route.fare    
  FROM route
  INNER JOIN opeator on opreator.id=route.id 
  INNER JOIN city as c1 on c1.id = route.dep
  INNER JOIN city as c2 on c2.id = route.dest
```

Comment: An alias was previously found. (near "route" at position 151)
An alias was previously found. (near "id" at position 157)

Comment: Error
SQL query: Documentation


SELECT 
    opreator.o_name,
    c1.name as dep,
    c2.name as  destination,
    route.fare    
  FROM route
  INNER JOIN opeator on opreator.id=route.id 
  INNER JOIN city as c1 on c1.id = route.dep
  INNER JOIN city as c2 on c2.id = route.dest LIMIT 0, 25
MySQL said: Documentation

#1046 - No database selected

Comment: No database selected   ....?????  is not related  to query .. anyway . i have also update the answer using c_name for city names..

Comment: You should set the database you want use

Answer (score 0):

When you `JOIN` two tables together the condition should be something like `WHERE table1.foreign_key = table2.primary_key`.

Your first join has a condition `WHERE table1.primary_key = table2.primary_key` which doesn't make sense. The primary key for one table has nothing to do with the primary key of the other table.

You also need to join to the `city` table twice, once for `dep` and again for `dest`.

Try this:

```
SELECT opreator.o_name, c1.c_name as dept, c2.c_name as destination, route.fare 
FROM route 
JOIN opreator ON route.opreator = opreator.id
JOIN city c1 ON route.dep = c1.id
JOIN city c2 ON route.dest = c2.id
```

Comment: Error
SQL query: Documentation


SELECT opreator.o_name, c1.c_name as dept, c2.c_name as destination, route.fare 
FROM route 
JOIN opreator ON route.opreator = opreator.id
JOIN city c1 ON route.dep = c1.id
JOIN city c2 ON route.dest = c2.id LIMIT 0, 25